# Install fonts on Windows 2019 Terminal Server for all users

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, fonts, windows-server

I'm running a Windows 2019 Terminal Server in a domain environment (and hence have no local admin account, just the domain admin account). When I log on as administrator and install fonts, they are installed just for this user (i.e. the admin).

The ttf files end up in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` and not in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. Also, the font is registered in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` and not in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.

I have even run a vbs script that installs fonts and ran this through a scheduled task using the SYSTEM account, but that put the fonts into `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`, i.e. local to the SYSTEM account.

Is there some way to force installation of fonts for all users?

Comment: Try to use [change user /install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/change-user) before installing the fonts. Use `change user /execute` to revert.

Comment: @harrymc: No, doesn't make a difference. (And thank you for reformatting, looks much better and easier to read now.)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is simple: When one right-clicks on a font, there is the well known option to "install" it. Right below is an option to "install for all users" which does what I want.

(Sorry for having been blind here, I have used this function so often that I hadn't read the menu anymore and totally overlooked the "install for all users".)

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking does not offer the option on some Windows Server versions.

For these, the solution is to create a GPO, namely "Install custom fonts", which would install the fonts from an accessible network share, "\fileserver\Fonts" for instance. For safety reasons, one should make the share read-only.

The GPO need to do 2 steps:
* copy the font file using the Computer\Preferences\Files path, using "update" mode and selecting source path as "\fileserver\Fonts\thefont.ttf" with a destination path being "c:\windows\fonts\thefont.ttf".
* record the font in the registry by creating a new entry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Fonts, with name "The Font (TrueType)" *the last part with the parenthesis is mandatory*, and with value "thefont.ttf".

Link the GPO in an Organizational Unit which your target servers/computers belong to. Connect to the machine and run "gpupdate /force" from command prompt (a.k.a cmd) or reboot the machine.

This nearly saved my week.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Using an admin command prompt, copy the font file(s) to the "c:\windows\fonts" folder. Then edit the registry to add the font file name to the list in (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts) Reboot the machine. I have used this to install a bar code font on our terminal server for our warehouse users.